Vimeo embed shows at thumbnail size (ACF)
Since ACF's 5.9.6 security release Vimeo embeds in my text field stopped working. I have added the following to my theme's functions.php:
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', 'acf_add_allowed_iframe_tag', 10, 2 );
function acf_add_allowed_iframe_tag( $tags, $context ) {
  if ( $context === 'post' ) {
    $tags['iframe'] = array(
        'src'             => true,
        'position'        => true,
        'top'             => true,
        'left'            => true,
        'height'          => true,
        'width'           => true,
        'frameborder'     => true,
        'allowfullscreen' => true,
        'autoplay'        => true,
        'picture-in-picture' => true,
    );
  }
  return $tags;
}

...Which now displays the video, but at a size much smaller than the containing div - test page below.
My embed code is (video id removed):
`<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://vimeo.com/event/[id]/embed" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe></div>`


The container, iframe, and everything I can style is set to width 100%.

Is the actual iframe element this small, or does vimeo simply render the video this tiny in an iframe that has the expected dimensions?

The iframe is set to width 100%, and does span the width of the containing div. Weirdly, on my live system with css updated in the browser, the controls sit where they should, and the image is still tiny, but this is not the case on my test system where I have updated the css file. I'm assuming it's something to do with how the video loads on page load
